# handle moves: proof

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology, morse-theory

In several 4-manifold textbooks, when handle moves (creation, cancellation, sliding) are discussed, they are explained using very helpful drawings.

However, I would like to know if there is a reference for a more rigorous proof.

It is sometimes hinted that this would use Morse theory...but I think I haven't found any mention of this in Milnor's classical book on the subject.

Any reference or proof is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by handle moves? Handle decomposition?

Comment: Are you asking for explicit formulas to describe handle moves, or the proofs of results involving them using explicit formulas?

Comment: Given a compact boundaryless manifold $M$, we can construct a Morse function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$, such that if the critical points of $f$ are $\{a,b,c,d,\ldots,e\}$, then $f(a)<f(b)<\ldots<f(e)$, and provided that $t_0<f(a)<t_1<\ldots<t_d<f(e)<t_e$, $\forall j$, $f^{-1}(t_{k-1},t_k)$ is homeomorphic to $(f^{-1}(t_{j-1}))\times [0,1])\cup H^{I}$, where $I$ is the index of the critical point (i.e., for $a$, $I=1$, for $b$, $I=2$, e.t.c.). If $I(a)\leq I(b)\leq I(c)\leq \ldots \leq I(e)$, this is a handle decomposition of $M$.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar : by handle moves, I mean moves used in Kirby calculus: handle sliding for instance.

Comment: @Lepanais Then my above comment applies for closed, smooth $4$-manifolds.

Comment: @PVAL I am looking for anything more than what is said for instance in R.E.Gompf and A.I. Stipsicz, 4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Indeed it does but I am not sure how it answers my question: your are describing handle decompositions while I am asking about handle slides

Comment: See http://www.math.harvard.edu/theses/senior/sablo/kirby.pdf, http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2082, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.1288.pdf.

Comment: Try Milnor's "Lectures on h-cobordism theorem". If I remember correctly, he does handle moves there with a great care.